# Rails 7, text Editor with Cloudinary like TinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, text-editor, actiontext

does anyone know of a text editor like TinyMCE that would work with Cloudinary?
I should mention that the Cloudinary plugin for TinyMCE is no longer maintained and doesn't work with Rails 7, as I have tested it.
Unless there's a possibility with ActionText to resize images like in TinyMCE? Or to achieve nearly the same functionality with ActionText as with TinyMCE? Thank you.

I have install ActionText and it works fine with Cloudinary, but i can't resize pictures.
So I install TinyMCE, but it doesn't work with Cloudinary. I contact Cloudinary, that told me that their plugin is no longer maintained.